# Mouse Input not being detected in Eclipse Java

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, mouseevent, mousemotionlistener

I was making a program that requires user input from the mouse, so I made a Mouse class that extends MouseAdapter. When tested it by clicking in the window, it did nothing. The code is provided below. Any help appreciated.

The Main Class

```
public class Main extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Main() {
        add(new Window());

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(720, 480);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setTitle("Mouse Input");
        setVisible(true);
        setResizable(false);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new Main();
    }

}
```

The Window Class

```
public class Window extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Window() {       
        addMouseMotionListener(new Mouse());

        Timer timer = new Timer(10, this);
        timer.start();

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

    }

}
```

The Mouse Class

```
class Mouse extends MouseAdapter{

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Clicked");
    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Dragged");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does nothing on click because you've added it as a MouseMotionListener to the JPanel but not as a MouseListener. You also need to pass your Mouse instance into the JPanel via the `addMouseListener(...)` method for MouseListener events to occur.

i.e.,

```
public Window() {
  Mouse myMouse = new Mouse();
  addMouseMotionListener(myMouse); // you already have this
  addMouseListener(myMouse);  // **** add this!! ****
```

Comment: I just realized, that it doesn't do anything when dragged.

Answer (score 1):

addMouseMotionListener(new Mouse());
        addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
            System.out.println("asdasd");

        }
    });
```